# Add WhatsApp images to Google Photo album in the cloud

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, google-photos, viber-messenger, cloud, auto-upload

I have a HUAWEI P20 phone and I am using the native Google Photos app to organize my photos on this device. Only the Camera folder is set for automatic upload to the cloud.

I am using Viber and WhatsApp on this phone. Their image folders are not uploaded automatically to Google Photos in the cloud and I do not need this, so that automatic uploading for this folders is turned off.

I also have a couple of albums in Google Photos to which I add particular photos from the Camera, Viber Images and WhatsApp Images folders. The problem is that only photos from the Camera and Viber Images folders I added to my albums on my HUAWEI device appear in the cloud (when I view them online at https://photos.google.com/). The images from the WhatsApp Images folder I add to the albums never appear online.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

---

P.S. I've looked at full image paths in Viber Images and WhatsApp Images folders to find any difference that may lead to this effect. It seems, paths for Viber and WhatsApp images have the same structure and this is not the source of the problem:

```
/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images/IMG-20200108-WA0000.jpg

/storage/emulated/0/viber/media/Viber Images/IMG-9104f1a4b3f873e1d9c8806bb9a8bd25-V.jpg
```

And sure, I am using the latest official firmware on my phone.

Answer (score -1):

You have to manually change the settings for it to be backed up.

In the Google Photos app:

- go to the Albums tab
- locate the PHOTOS ON DEVICE section
- scroll to find the WhatsApp Images folder
- when you click to open it, on top, right after the title, there is a `Back up & sync` switch -> click to activate it.

If you also want to back up the videos, there's a separate folder for that, you have to activate the switch for it too - and for any other local folder you might want to have in the cloud.

Comment: Guys and girls, please, do not tell me how to enable automatic upload of WhatsApp or Viber images into the cloud. I KNOW HOW TO DO THAT AND I DO NOT NEED THIS! I receive a lot of images in Viber and WhatsApp, but I want to store only SOME OF THEM in my albums online. This works as expected for Viber but not for WhatsApp. I am trying to understand why.